# Input field validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a input field that should accept only these format (*d- digit, c- character*):

```
d.d
d.d.d
d.d.c
```

My code:

```
var format1 = /[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}/g; // d.d
var format2 = /[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}/g; // d.d.d    
var format3 = /[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}/g; // d.d.c    

if (format1.test(input)) {
    format1Con = true;
}
if (format2.test(input)) {
    format2Con = true;
}
if (format3.test(input)) {
    format3Con = true;
}
```

This code allows some wrong type values. 
For example - 
          1.2.3.33,
          1.2.ccccc (Here only one character should be aaccepted)

Please help with exact regular expression for my field format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/^\d\.\d+(?:\.(?:\d|[a-z]))?$/i
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS1jU0/3)

The regex matches...

- `^` - Beginning of a string
- `\d` - a digit
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.(?:\d|[a-z]))?` - an optional group matching...

  - `\.` - literal dot and...
  - `(?:\d|[a-z])` - either a single digit or letters from `[a-zA-Z]` range (since `i` modifier is used)
- `$` - End of string

  ```js
  var re = /^\d\.\d+(?:\.(?:\d|[a-z]))?$/; 
  document.write('1.2.3.33: ' + re.test('1.2.3.33') + "<br/>");
  document.write('1.2.ccccc: ' + re.test('1.2.ccccc') + "<br/>");
  document.write('1.2: ' + re.test('1.2') + "<br/>");
  document.write('1.22: ' + re.test('1.22') + "<br/>");
  document.write('1.22.3: ' + re.test('1.22.3') + "<br/>");
  document.write('1.2.3: ' + re.test('1.2.3') + "<br/>");
  document.write('1.2.x: ' + re.test('1.2.x') + "<br/>");
  ```

Comment: Thanks stribizhev. It's working but if I want to give input like this format 1.12.1. In this scenario, should I use this one [0-9]{1,} instead of d.

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that `{1,}` limiting quantifier in JS can be replaced with `+` quantifier.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it works for you, and upvoting if it turned out helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your RegEXP like this:

```
var format1 = /^[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}$/g; // d.d
var format2 = /^[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}$/g; // d.d.d    
var format3 = /^[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}$/g; // d.d.c
```

Where `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string.